# How to delete the ^H^H characters in a file?

Tags: linux, vim

I am doing a show run > filename to save some cisco configs. It works fine, but on the save config there are those non printable characters that are annoying me.

It is showing in vim (also on other programs like kate) in this way:

```
aaa new-model
 --More-- ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H        ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H!
!
aaa authentication login default local
```

Instead of

```
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa authentication login default local
```

According to wikipedia ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace#.5EH)), this character represents the backpsace keypress, and programs such as 'less' present it in the proper readable form.
I don't know if this can be fixed on the origin, or disabled in vim at least, any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Is it possible that you set that as a fillchar?

Comment: If you type `terminal length 0` before you dump the config, it won't pause after every screenful.

Comment: I am using autocommand show running, and in this case the instruccions are single line only, hence I can't run the terminal length 0

Comment: I do find these characters in vim, by if you want to view the file without these characters you can use `cat` command. In my case, I have created auto commands. They will replace all these control characters with empty string or whatever equivalent to them while opening the file.  So, every time when I open the file,  it replaces them all and shows me the correct text. Also, remember that these changes are temporary and are ignored once the file is changed. For example, I have changed ^M to new line while opening a file.

Answer (score 3):

You may just simply substitute all of them. For example,

```
:%s/<C-v><C-h>//g
```

Note that `<C-v>` and `<C-h>` mean ctrl-v and ctrl-h respectively. This allows you to insert unprintable characters (such as `<C-h>`) into your substitute command.

This *will* remove all of them, but I can't guarantee the result will be formatted perfectly, since I'm not sure why they are there in the first place.

Comment: It does nothing unfortunately, vim says "E486: Pattern not Found: <C-v><C-h>

Comment: @user322049  `<C-v><C-h>` is *not* the text you enter. It's control-v followed by control-h

Comment: Ok, I finally could test it, but doensn't work either, althought in vim I see :s/^H//g, I get "E486: Pattern not found:" (i just uploaded the file here if you want to check out https://gist.github.com/7da907cef37078056965b4b18547a135)

Comment: @user322049 Well, I can guarantee this is the right solution, and have manually confirmed that it works, so you're probably doing something wrong. Are you typing `^H` (Two characters, caret then 'h'), are you typing ctrl-v, ctrl-h?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet that will naively try to treat the character as an erase character (`cat -v` is used to show control characters in caret notation similar to opening the file in vim):

```
bash$ cat -v file
aaa new-model
 --More-- ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H        ^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H!
!
aaa authentication login default local

bash$ sed -e $':b; s/.\b//; tb;' | cat -v
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa authentication login default local
```

This would get you closer to the actual terminal output than simply stripping all the erase characters.

Answer (score 0):

I believe for this cisco outputs, you want to get rid of the whole `--More--` line there. You can do so this way:

`cat cisco-output.txt | grep -v '^ *--More.*\x08' > cisco-output-clean.txt`

The result will look as:

```
aaa new-model
!
aaa authentication login default local
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it's weird because on the screen it shows the proper characters:
`$ cat original > destination #keeps the backspace character
$ cat original | grep -v '^ *--More.*\x0 > destination # keeps backspaces
$ cat original #show only proper characters in screen`